# Не работает onAttach

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Я создал `ListFragment` (знаю, что есть `RecyclerView`, просто книгу читаю). В методе `onAttach` я пытаюсь получить ссылку на активность, чтобы вызывать ее метод. После первого запуска — мое приложение не работало. После 10ти минут раздумий я нашел ошибку! `onAttach(Context context)` не вызывается, а `onAttach(Activity activity)` (deprecated) — вызывается! Вот методы:

```
@Override //РАБОТАЕТ
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    listener = (WorkoutListListener) activity;
}

@Override //НЕ РАБОТАЕТ
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    listener = (WorkoutListListener) context;
}
```

Так в чем же разница этих двух методов? Почему устаревший работает, а обычный нет?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подробно на англо-саксонсом [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32077086/3212712)

Кратко:

`ListFragment` есть только в пакете `android.app` и добавляется в активити через `FragmentManager` вместо `SupportFragmentManager`. Из-за этого не используется метод `onAttach(Context context)` на устройствах с `API<23`, а используется `onAttach(Activity activity)`

Решением может быть помечание обоих методов соответствующими аннотациями для вызова нужной версии на определённых уровнях `API` и делегирование продолжения логики в общий для всех `API` собственный метод, в коем вы уже можете кастовать контекст к активити (помня, что класс итоговой активити разнится в зависимости от уровня API (решение - кастовать к интерфейсу, реализуемому активити):

```
/*
 * onAttach(Context) не вызовется до API 23 версии вместо этого будет вызван onAttach(Activity), коий устарел с 23 API
 * Так что вызовем onAttachToContext
 */
@TargetApi(23)
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    onAttachToContext(context);
}

/*
 * устарел с 23 API
 * Так что вызовем onAttachToContext
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        onAttachToContext(activity);
    }
}

/*
 * Вызовется в момент присоединения фрагмента к активити
 */
protected void onAttachToContext(Context context) {
     //здесь всегда есть контекст и метод всегда вызовется.
     //тут можно кастовать контест к активити.
     //но лучше к реализуемому ею интерфейсу
     //чтоб не проверять из какого пакета активити в каждом из случаев
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понял, что означает выражение `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M`, но на сколько я понял — Вы попросту перенаправляете оба метода на один, который вызовется в любом случае?

Comment: `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M` это проверка на то, что версия текущей системы меньше 6 андроида. И да - по ссылке предложено решение перенаправления кода в единый для всех версий метод.