# Допустимо ли хранить статический экземпляр Activity, если она в приложении одна?

Tags: android, activity

На самом деле нет, не одна. В приложении есть активити на старте - она же - заглушка, пока идет получение данных от сервера, вторая - сообщение об ошибке подключения к интернету, ее я показываю только при ошибках. Третья и основная это контейнер для множества фрагментов, которыми я управляю при помощи NavigationDrawer. На тот момент, когда загружена основная активити - нет шансов, что я увижу остальные две до перезапуска приложения (они существуют лишь на старте). Допустимо ли в таком случае хранить статический экземпляр активити в ней самой? Инициализировать, допустим, в onCreate (a можно и обнулять и реинициализировать при уходе ее на задний план и возвращении оттуда). Или это все равно bad idea?

UPD

Передавая ссылку на этот экземпляр, допустим в адаптер и храня её в нестатическом поле, мы делаем этот адаптер неубиваемым для GC или нет?

Comment: А зачем Вам статическая ссылка на активити внутри активити? В любом случае ссылка на активити доступна и так, а наличие статических полей в активити на непримитивные данные - источник многочисленных ошибок.

Comment: почему то по мере выхода новых build version (мое предположение), многое в проекте стало меняться. Началось с того, что местами поехала разметка, а местами getActivity() или getContext() во фрагменте стало возвращать null. Объективно я пересмотрю это, но на данный момент это в релизе и пользователи не могут пользоваться приложением, что вызывает массу негативных эмоций. Потому и хочется понять, допустимо ли такое решение хотя бы временно

Comment: @iamthevoid, скорее всего вам надо просто откатиться до версий, где всё было стабильно. Новые версии - всегда новые баги. А про getContext во врагменте посмотрите [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507012/17609) - контест (и активити из него) лучше получать в соответствующем методе жизненного цикла